# How to correctly link css from theme directory if building a page in the wordpress root folder?

Tags: css, wordpress, directory

I’m building a page in the root wordpress folder. So I’m trying to connect styles from my theme’s folder.

I thought it would be correct to use `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` to build a path. But when I do use it, I get an `Call to undefined function...` error.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href= "<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/css/styles.css">
```

Comment: The way you're asking ("a page in the root wordpress folder") implies you're not using a regular WordPress page but building something else. For the `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` function to be available the WordPress core must be loaded. This can either be done by requiring wp_load.php in the root directory first, or better, using a regular page with the permalink adapted to your needs.

Comment: @Damocles thx, that helped!